# Is it possible to return a string from C# to Javascript using Xamarin.iOS?

Tags: javascript, c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have used [HybridWebView from XLabs](https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/blob/master/src/Forms/XLabs.Forms.iOS/Controls/HybridWebView/HybridWebViewRenderer.cs) to build a HybridWebView that can communicate with C# code. I have build custom renderers to do this. In simple terms I have:

**iOS**

```
public class HybridWebViewRenderer : ViewRenderer<HybridWebView, WKWebView>, IWKScriptMessageHandler
{      
    const string JavaScriptFunctionTemplate = "function {0}(){{window.webkit.messageHandlers.invokeAction.postMessage('{0}|' + JSON.stringify(arguments));}}";
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<HybridWebView> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (Control == null)
        {
            userController = new WKUserContentController();
            foreach (var f in Element.RegisteredFunctions.Where(ff => !ff.IsInjected))
            {
                var script = new WKUserScript(new NSString(string.Format(JavaScriptFunctionTemplate, f.Name)), WKUserScriptInjectionTime.AtDocumentEnd, false);
                userController.AddUserScript(script);
                f.Injected();
            }

            userController.AddScriptMessageHandler(this, "invokeAction");
            var config = new WKWebViewConfiguration { UserContentController = userController };               

            var webView = new WKWebView(Frame, config)
            {
                NavigationDelegate = new CustomWKNavigationDelegate(this.Element)
            };

            SetNativeControl(webView);
        }
        if (e.OldElement != null)
        {
            userController.RemoveAllUserScripts();
            userController.RemoveScriptMessageHandler("invokeAction");
            var hybridWebView = e.OldElement as HybridWebView;
            hybridWebView.Cleanup();
        }
        if (e.NewElement != null)
        {
            Load(Element.Uri);
        }
    }

    public void DidReceiveScriptMessage(WKUserContentController userContentController, WKScriptMessage message)
    {

        var bits = message.Body.ToString().Split('|');
        if (bits.Count() == 2)
        {
            var result = Element.InvokeFunction(bits[0], bits[1]);
            //How do I return result back to Javascript function?
        }
    }
```

the `InvokeFunction` method returns a value `result` which is a string.

How can I return this string `result` back to the javascript function which was injected?

**Edit**

Do I need to edit my `JavaScriptFunctionTemplate` I notice in the XLabs they have a similar [template](https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/blob/7a58dc349f17351813afa24df97ef7fea545a833/src/Forms/XLabs.Forms.Shared/Controls/HybridWebViewRenderer.cs#L33) but append something to the [end](https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/blob/7a58dc349f17351813afa24df97ef7fea545a833/src/Forms/XLabs.Forms.Shared/Controls/HybridWebViewRenderer.cs#L86)

Comment: I suspect you would inplement an interface that contains properties so you can invoke a property change which would push the value (in this case result) back upto your PCL(?) or Xamarin.Forms project (?)

Comment: @Digitalsa1nt The value is already coming back from the `PCL` into the `result` property in the code above. The problem I'm having is returning this `result` back to the `Javascript` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there any reason why you couldn't simply 're-call' your function using the methods [described here?](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/controls/call-javascript/)

Their example:

```
void OnCallJavaScriptButtonClicked (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  ...
  int number = int.Parse (numberEntry.Text);
  int end = int.Parse (stopEntry.Text);

  webView.Eval (string.Format ("printMultiplicationTable({0}, {1})", number, end));
}
```

So yours would be something like:

```
const string JavaScriptFunctionTemplate = "function {0}(){{window.webkit.messageHandlers.invokeAction.postMessage('{0}|' + JSON.stringify(arguments));}}";

public void DidReceiveScriptMessage(WKUserContentController userContentController, WKScriptMessage message)
{
     var bits = message.Body.ToString().Split('|');

     if (bits.Count() == 2)
     {
         var result = Element.InvokeFunction(bits[0], bits[1]);

         webView.Eval(string.Format ("JavaScriptFunctionTemplate({0})", result)); // or however your parameter structure is.
     }
}
```

**EDIT:**

Just want to encorporate the [LINK](http://www.joshuakehn.com/2014/10/29/using-javascript-with-wkwebview-in-ios-8.html) that the OP found as it looks to be a solid guide to the solution in Objective-C which is fairly straight forward to convert to Xamarin C#.

Comment: This is the only way I found to communicate between my app and webview on `iOS`. More information [here](http://www.joshuakehn.com/2014/10/29/using-javascript-with-wkwebview-in-ios-8.html)